# setBackgroundResource of TextView in listitem

Tags: android

I've got an activity that presents a `listview` of tracks of songs. When an item is clicked, it streams the appropriate media file. I have a textview in each row that displays the length of the track. When the track is playing, I switch the `backgroundresource` of the `textview` in the row to a pause button drawable. In other words, when it's ready to play, it displays a play button and when its currently playing it displays a pause button. Simple enough....

Currently, I'm doing something like this to set the drawable to pause button if the `mediaplayer` is playing:

`if(mp.isPlaying()) {
            _player.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausebtn);
            _player.setText(" :" + String.valueOf(mp.getDuration()/1000));`

I'm doing this in my Runnable which has the `mediaplayer` callback of `onPrepared`.

Problem is that I need the drawable to be set in THAT list item, i.e. the one which was clicked and whose track is being played. How can I grab hold of which one was clicked and set ITS textview to the new drawable?

Here's the full code:

```
package com.me.player

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import com.mtv.datahandler.Artist;
import com.mtv.datahandler.DataBaseHelper;
import com.mtv.datahandler.Track;
import com.mycompany.http.HttpRequest;


public class ArtistAudio extends ControllerActivity implements OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener{

    private int METHOD_TYPE = 0;
    private static final int GET_AUDIO = 1;

    int CURRENT_POSITION = 0;
    int DURATION = 0;

    public static final String AUDIO_FEED_URL = "http://direct.rhapsody.com/metadata/data/getTopTracksForArtist.xml?blabla";
    public static final int MAX_TRACKS = 200;
    ArrayList<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
    Artist artist;

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private int mSongPlaying = 0;
    TextView _player;

    @Override
    protected void progressRunnableComplete() {
        if(isFinishing()){
            return;
        }
        if(METHOD_TYPE == GET_AUDIO){
            setList();
        }
    }

    public void setList(){
        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        //      ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        if(listview == null){
            setContent(R.layout.artistaudio);
            listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        }

        //      listview.addHeaderView();
        listview.setCacheColorHint(0);
        listview.setAdapter(new TrackListAdapter());
        listview.setSelector(R.drawable.listbackground);
        listview.setDividerHeight(1);
        listview.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_dotted_line_horz));
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TrackClicked(arg2);
            }
        });
    }

    public void TrackClicked(int arg2){



        mSongPlaying = arg2;


        Track track = tracks.get(arg2);
        String url = track.requestInfo("previewURL");

        mHandler.post(new PlaySong(url));









//      mHandler.post(new PlaySong("http://dc237.4shared.com/img/315443275/33f14ef2/dlink__2Fdownload_2F9y5VGjVt_3Ftsid_3D20100705-131850-40aa0b87/preview.mp3"));
    }

    public void setDuration(int n) {
        DURATION = n;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Audio Clips");
        setContent(R.layout.artistaudio);

        Object o = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("artist");
        if(o!=null){
            artist = (Artist)o;
        }

        progressRunnable(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                getTracks();
            }
        }, "Loading. Please Wait...",false);


    }

    protected void getTracks() {
        METHOD_TYPE = GET_AUDIO;
        if(!DataBaseHelper.isOnline(this)){
            RUNNABLE_STATE = RUNNABLE_FAILED;
            return;
        }
        HttpRequest req;
        try {
            req = new HttpRequest(new URL(AUDIO_FEED_URL+artist.requestInfo("rhapsodyID")));
            Document doc = req.AutoXMLNoWrite();
            NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("e");
            tracks= new ArrayList<Track>();
            for(int i=0; i<items.getLength(); i++){
                Track newsitem = new Track(items.item(i));
                tracks.add(newsitem);   
            }
            RUNNABLE_STATE = RUNNABLE_SUCCESS;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            RUNNABLE_STATE = RUNNABLE_FAILED;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        try{mp.stop();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        try{mp.reset();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        try{mp.release();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        mp = null;

    }

    private class TrackListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return tracks.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return tracks.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AudioCell blogView = null;
            if (convertView != null) {
                if(convertView.getClass() == TextView.class){
                    convertView = null;
                }
            }
            if (convertView == null) {
                blogView = new AudioCell(parent.getContext());
            }
            else {
                blogView = (AudioCell) convertView;
            }
            blogView.display(position);
            return blogView;
        }
    } 

    /** this class is responsible for rendering the data in the model, given the selection state */
    class AudioCell extends RelativeLayout {

        TextView _title;



        int currentPosition;



        public AudioCell(Context mContext) {
            super(mContext);
            _createUI(mContext);
        }

        /** create the ui components */
        private void _createUI(Context m) {


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            _player = new TextView(m);
            _player.setId(2);
            _player.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbtn);
            _player.setText(":30");





            addView(_player);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL,1);
            _player.setLayoutParams(params);


            _title = new TextView(m);
            _title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);       
            params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)(44*metrics.density));
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL,1);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, _player.getId());

            params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
            _title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            _title.setLayoutParams(params);
            _title.setId(102);
            addView(_title);
            params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)(44*metrics.density));

//          _player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//              
//              @Override
//              public void onClick(View v) {
//                  PlaySong.PlaySong("http://http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples/2544.mp3");
//                  
//              }
//          });
//          














        }

        /** update the views with the data corresponding to selection index */
        public void display(int index) {
            _title.setText(tracks.get(index).requestInfo("name"));
        }
    }

    private class PlaySong implements Runnable{
        String songURL;

        public PlaySong(String url){
            songURL = url;
        }

        public void run(){
            try{mp.stop();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


            try{mp.reset();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

            if(mp==null){
                createPlayer();
            }
            try{mp.reset();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{mp.setDataSource(songURL);}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            try{mp.prepareAsync();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}



        }
    }

    public void createPlayer(){
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{mp.reset();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
//      if(mSongPlaying<tracks.size()-1)
//      {
//          TrackClicked(mSongPlaying+1);
//      }



        _player.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbtn);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer inMP) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        mp.start();
        if(mp.isPlaying()) {
            _player.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausebtn);
            _player.setText(" :" + String.valueOf(mp.getDuration()/1000));


        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, my inner class `AudioCell` which extends `RelativeLayout` is what I'm using for the rows of my `ListView`....

Any thoughts? Where should I be setting the drawable and how can I make sure it does it only for the row that was clicked (i.e. for the track that's actually being played).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `TrackClicked` method's siggnature. pass both `arg1` and `arg3` from `onItemClick` and in the `TrackClicked` method do this `arg1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thebackground);`

Comment: that sets the backgroundresource of the entire row. I wanna set the background of one of the textviews within the row.

Comment: try this then. cast `arg1` as `AudioCell`. Assuming you want to change the background of the `_title` field try this `((AudioCell)arg1)._title.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thebackground);`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your TrackClicked method, add this:

```
getAdapter().getChildAt(arg2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thebackground);
```